# Excel: Find Distribution, Several Equations

Tags: excel, distribution, solver

I want to find the perfect distribution for the lines 3 and 4 with the cells A3, B3, C3, D3, A4, B4, C4, D4.

My idea was to use the solver function in excel but I cannot find a solution.

In the column E are the sums for the rows.
In line 5 are the sums for the columns.
The overall sum is 40.

I know there are possibly many solutions but I have this problem quite often and sometimes it's more complex and I think in such a case there could be only one solution.

[image]

Comment: For those of us who might not be stats-savvy, could you also show us what the expected output is for lines 3 and 4?

Answer (score 1):

This works with the solver as so:
[image]

Its one solution, there are others - as I found one just by typing in numbers... But the solver will find a solution using the Simplex LP solver. Cell E5 has the sum of A5:D5.

Comment: Therefore in line 5 and column E formulas are need, right?

Comment: Yes, the formulas are the sums as you stated, E1 =sum(A1:D1) and A5 =sum(A1:A4) etc